# Dúvida em uma consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Modelo DER]

Através desse modelo de DER eu gostaria de fazer uma consulta sql que me retorne a seguinte informação: Escreva um comando que apresente quantos clientes são solteiros.

Comment: já tentou alguma coisa? pode postar??

Answer (score 1):

Vamos começar analisando o seu diagrama de tabelas.

Dado o seu problema, apenas **duas** tabelas de todas as informadas são importantes para o buscar o que precisa.

Perceba que há uma tabela `Cliente` e uma tabela `Conjuge`. Ambas se relacionam através da coluna `Cod_Cli`, como pode perceber pela "chavezinha" amarela que liga uma a outra.

Dito isso, podemos entender que apenas clientes casados (ou namorando) irão ter um cônjuge, ou seja, irão ter seu código referenciado na tabela `Conjuge`.

Assim sendo, montamos um comando SQL que irá contar quantos clientes não possuem seu código referenciado na tabela `Conjuge`, identificando assim, os clientes solteiros:

```
SELECT COUNT(cliente.Cod_Cli) 
FROM Cliente cliente 
WHERE cliente.Cod_Cli NOT INT (SELECT conj.Cod_Cli FROM Conjuge conj);
```